# Eclipse plugins for Play & Lift to create new projects

Tags: eclipse-plugin, playframework, lift

I am a beginner on Play and Lift frameworks and I have a question:
Is there any Eclipse plugin for either Play framework and/or Lift framework enabling us to create a new Play/Lift project directly from Eclipse IDE (kind from Eclipse we can do File>New>Play Project (and/or Lift Project))?!

Comment: I understand that it is preferable to load the project from inside Eclipse but are there any other reasons? Otherwise `play eclipse` works really well. You'll have to run the command only when something in `Build.scala`, `build.properties` or `plugins.sbt` changes. Not very often I guess.

Comment: Scala IDE plugin for Play 2.1 https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-ide-play2

Answer (score 0):

There is a "lifty" plugin (but it may be outdated) which can create parts of the project from SBT:
http://lifty.github.io/Installing+The+Plugin.html

Anyway, the best way to create liftweb projects is, as I personally think, to start from https://github.com/lift/lift_25_sbt/
This is a small sample project created by some of Lift's commiters. It contains 2 simple pages and a basic setup. After that you can do:

`./sbt eclipse with-sources=true` to create an eclipse project